# Delimit R dataframe column ignoring commas in quote

Tags: r

I am trying to split a data frame column delimiting on stand-alone commas but ignoring commas in single quotes. I have tried several things but can't get any to work.

Here is a simplified version of `df`:

```
V1
'914061', 'Palo Alto'
'930061', 'Brooklyn, New York, USA'
```

Desired output:

```
V1, V2
914061,Palo Alto
930061, Brooklyn, New York, USA (location in one cell)
```

I tried this but it split up Brooklyn and New York and USA (and returned a warning about vector length)

```
df2 <- data.frame(do.call('rbind',strsplit(as.character(df$V1),',',fixed=TRUE)))
```

I also tried this but get "Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument"

```
df2 <- read.delim(df$V1, header=F, sep=',', dec = '.', stringsAsFactors=F , quote = "\"" , fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `quote='"'` where you should have used `quote="'"`. And force `read.csv` to read both columns as variables rather than turning one into rownames.

```
read.csv(df$V1, quote="'", row.names=NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks...this worked perfectly :) Used read.csv(data.csv, quote="'", row.names=NULL)